# Not able to query MongoDB.Bson.ObjectId using ElasticSearch Nest Client

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-query, objectid

I have a c# model which represents a collection/table in `MongoDB`. Assume it looks something like:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public ObjectId ClaimId { get; set; }
    pub string SomeStringProperty { get; set; }
    //..other props
}
```

This model has several properties with type `ObjectId` which is part of [MonboDB.Bson Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MongoDB.Bson/).

**Problem**: When I index my `List<MyModel>` to my `ElasticSearch` server using [NEST](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NEST), all `ObjectId` type fields of `MyModel` look like following structure in ElasticSearch:

[image]

**Question**: How can I query the data in ElasticSearch having ObjectId field in 'where' clause of query?

When I have to filter over string field `SomeStringProperty` of `MyModel`, I can do following, which works good:

```
var result = 
            _elasticClient.Search<MyModel>(x => x
            .Index("mymodels")
            .Query(q => q
                   .Term(p => p.SomeStringProperty.Suffix("keyword"), filterValue)
                )
            )
```

But how can I apply same filter on ObjectId field? I tried few things but it wasn't matching, and I think that is because its value has completely been changed in elasticsearch server. Is there a way to query over this field?

I went through several articles on SO, but couldn't find similar or exactly like this issue. And secondly, I'm just beginner with ElasticSearch world. Any help/guideline will be appreciated.